# Hierarchical MultIndex table with loop with Python

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, tabular

First of all there might be more mistakes in my code than I know, the fact that I am new I do not understand everything at all. I am trying to index my table like the following picture: 
I am reading columns a and b incrementally and appending them together, in total I read 500 files with each 15000 rows. Now I need to MultiIndex them like in the following picture but I couldn't find a way to do that within a loop, with pandas hierarchical index and MultIndex. Is there a way to do it with a loop for all of the datapoints and numbers?

[image]

---

```
all_data = pd.DataFrame()

for f in glob.glob("path_in_dir"):
    df = pd.read_table(f, delim_whitespace=True, 
                   names=('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'),
                   dtype={'A': np.float32, 'B': np.float32, 'C': np.float32,
                          'D': np.float32,'E': np.float32, 'F': np.float32,
                          'G': np.float32,'H': np.float32})

    all_data = all_data.append(df,ignore_index=True)

all_data.index.names = ['numbers']
```

## show all data

`print(all_data)`

I am using append but I read somewhere that is also not efficient like `pd.concat` which would be important to increase the speed and reduce memory usage. When I try it in this way: `all_data = pd.concat(df,ignore_index=True)` I get the error:

first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"

At the moment I only get the d columns but counting from 0 to the end of the rows, so for 2 files till 30000. So i am not splitting the counting to each files datapoint.

When I extend the index to: `all_data.index.names =[datapoints, numbers]
get the message ValueError: Length of new names must be 1, got 2

Comment: What difficulties are you encountering? What's your input source - have you managed to get a single DataFrame with all your data in? Have you then tried just doing an `.set_index(['col1', 'col2'])`. At the moment - it's unclear what to suggest to help as we don't know what you've tried or where you are.

Comment: @JonClements Thank you for your help please see my answer below to get a better idea about my problem

Comment: Can you post an example of what your original data looks like?

Comment: @IanThompson Can not post a photo of the data. The data looks like a matrix with 8 columns and 15000 rows each file, with values between 0 and 1. All datas in one column are one datapoint later. In total 500 files. I want that all the 15000 are counted as a MultIndex and also for each file later than the index outside to count the 'filenumber' or datapoint as well. Can you please help me to solve my problem ?

Comment: Why are you ignoring your index if you want each row to be indexed? Also, your for loop isn't going to run because 1. indentation errors and 2. all_data wasn't defined before you tried to append to it. What are the types of files? .csv? .xlsx? .tsv? etc...

Comment: 1. Looks like I put them when I copied the code, it is running and 2. all_data was defined above but I missed it, sorry for that. I am importing .txt fiiles your code above is good but now my reading is not working. What do I have to change that it is reading and making the index like your example?

Comment: @IanThompson can you please help to solve my problem ? I do not want to save the filenames as the datapoint index I just want to count them

Comment: @IanThompson your answer below fits really well, thank you!

Comment: @newpyguy No problem. Please consider selecting it as the correct answer. Thanks and Happy New Year!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Note that you won't need to declare `all_data` because you can do it within the loop. The dictionary part also helps with creating the multi-index that you are looking for.

```
# make a test txt file
txt = open('df1.txt', mode = 'w')
txt.write('1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 \n2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16')
txt.close()

# make a dictionary for storing the dataframes
dataframes = {}

# import files with for-loop in my current working directory (otherwise a different path)
for file in enumerate(glob.glob(os.getcwd()+'/*.txt')): # using *.txt to only retrieve .txt files
    dataframes.update({file[0] + 1: pd.read_table(file[1], delim_whitespace = True, names = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'), dtype = {
        'A' : np.float32,
        'B' : np.float32,
        'C' : np.float32,
        'D' : np.float32,
        'E' : np.float32,
        'F' : np.float32,
        'G' : np.float32,
        'H' : np.float32
    })})

# concat dataframes together
df = pd.concat(dataframes, axis = 0)

# label indices to match wanted output
df.index.names = ['Datapoint', 'number']

df
```

[image: output]

Comment: thank you, I am new to Python but I tried to do something like this: First I am reading all my files into one big dataframe than I am making my datapoints and numbers,  in this case I harcoded it for two files. I want to have that automated and if possible also not using much memory. Please see my answer below for the code.